# cron job is not able to open log4sh file

Tags: logging, cron

I have set up the cron job and downloaded the log4sh software and extracted.
I am able to run the test log4sh sample from putty ( Command promt `ex:/test-propetires`).

But When it is called from Cron Job it is giving the below exception.
`error: could not load (log4sh) or Can't open ./log4sh`

- List item
- test-properties file

  ```
  #! /bin/sh
  # $Id: test-properties,v 1.1.1.1 2004/12/31 12:15:46 sfsetse Exp
  log_msg()
  {  logger_debug "(my debug message) $1"
    logger_info "(my info message) $1"}
  #set -x
  # load log4sh
  if [ -r log4sh ]; then
  . ./log4sh
  else
  echo "error: could not load (log4sh)"
  exit 1
  fi
  log_msg "log4sh now loaded"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Most of troubles with things like "it works in my console but not with my cron job" are about variable environments like PATH.
You should use absolute path to check for log4sh or be sure that it's in the PATH used by cron.